# Formulário do Django vinculado a registro

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, formulário

Tenho duas tabelas no Django (Jogo e Gol) e estou tentando criar um formulário para elas:

```
class Jogo(models.Model):
    ativo = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    dataHoraInicio = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Data e Hora de Início')
    dataHoraFim = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Data e Hora de Fim', null = True, blank = True)

class Gol(models.Model):
    jogo = models.ForeignKey(Jogo, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    minuto = models.IntegerField(help_text = 'Minuto do jogo em que aconteceu o gol')
    jogador = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

Minha dúvida está em vincular os campos do formulário aos registros da tabela Gol de modo que, para cada registro, haja os campos 'minuto' e 'jogador', onde o usuário possa modificar os dados da tabela.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Mas qual é a sua duvida especificamente? o que vc ja tentou? se vc nunca fez nada com forms "vinculado a registros" em django, fica dificil explicar em uma resposta, sugiro que faça o [tutorial da documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) desede o inicio, na parte 4 é abordado o uso de forms.

Comment: Boa tarde amigo. Normalmente os campos do formulário são vinculados aos campos da tabela do banco. O que estou tentando é vincular os campos do formulário com os registros do banco e não com os campos da tabela. Outro exemplo parecido: fazer um formulário com uma checkbox para cada permissão de usuário na parte de autenticação do Django. Entende meu ponto?

Comment: Não, não necessariamente os campos "são vinculados" a alguma coisa, vc é que configura isso, vincular, de forma direta, algo do front-end (no caso o seu formulário) a algo do back-end (no caso o banco) é impossível no django, pois o mesmo segue o padrão MVC (chamado por alguns como MVT, por causa das templates). Repito, não perca tempo, o que vc quer esta no tutorial que indiquei.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, amigo. Acredito que eu não tenha me expressado bem. Eu sei que é possível criar formulários de forma direta, sem vínculo com um banco de dados. Já conheço esses conceitos mais básicos e tenho analisado esse tutorial desde a versão 1.6.5 do Django, quando comecei a trabalhar com o framework em 2015. Minha dúvida é em outro ponto em específico e, talvez, esteja na documentação mas não o encontrei.

Comment: O que quero é dinamizar a geração dos campos de um formulário com base nos registros de uma tabela do banco, a exemplo de criar uma série de checkboxes com as permissões de usuários no django.contrib.auth ou do exemplo que havia postado anteriormente. Você conhece alguma função do django.forms.Form que possa ser reescrita e que é carregada no momento em que o formulário é renderizado no template, por exemplo?